# Is Dependency Validation possible in KnockOut.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, knockout.js

Usually validations work independent with respective binded content, eg http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/JL26Z/53/

But I have two text boxes `name1` & `name2`, as mentioned in fiddle, I need to do show validation is failed if following condition fails:

- `name1` is mandatory if `name2` is not entered.
- `name2` is mandatory if `name1` is not entered.
- if `name1` & `name2` left empty i need to show error message i.e validations failed.

If I got you confused: in short I am looking for validations to pass if text is entered in any of the textboxes.

Comment: https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Conditional-Validation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331948/knockout-validation-of-two-interdependent-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like [@delixfe suggested in another question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14522474/57508):

```
var Phone = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.name1 = ko.observable("");
    self.name2 = ko.observable("");

    self.numbersHaveNoValue = ko.computed(function () {
        var value1 = self.name1(), value2 = self.name2();
        return !ko.validation.rules.required.validator(value1, true) &&
               !ko.validation.rules.required.validator(value2, true);
    });

    self.Validation = ko.validatedObservable([
        self.name1.extend({ required: { onlyIf: self.numbersHaveNoValue }}),
        self.name2.extend({ required: { onlyIf: self.numbersHaveNoValue }})
    ]);
}
```

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/55/)

Comment: Andreas i will look into it and let you know .

Comment: when i enter something in textbox2 and press submit leaving textbox1 empty its shooting me error which should not happen . any ideas ?

Comment: gotcha bro .! used additional `ko.computed` . cheers

Comment: nah, this was a mistake in the first version, where I did `...required.validator(valu1, true)` for both name1 and name2

Comment: ha yes thats right . i changed to value1 to value 2 rather keeping both same its doesn't work earlier but now its working like charm intrestingly .